# How do I check to see if I have JDBC installed on my system?

Tags: java, mysql, macos, jdbc

I how does one check to see whether or not they have JDBC connector for mySQL installed in Mac OS?

Comment: You normally don't 'install' Java libraries. They are included on the classpath of a specific application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` inside a `try-catch` block in order to confirm if the MySQL JDBC driver is in the classpath or not. If it won't be found in the classpath, `ClassNotFoundException` will be thrown which you can capture and show an error message as shown below:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error: MySQL JDBC driver not found.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to instantiate the mysql jdbc driver class":

```
try {
        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
        // broken Java implementations
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle the error
    }
```

Comment: Lennart Steinke - This is not correct. There are multiple problems with this code: (1)  You have use a raw type for `Class`. It should be `Class<?>` (2) `Class.forName` throws `ClassNotFoundException` which needs to be handled using `try-catch` or the method, where this code is there, should declare `throws ClassNotFoundException`. (3) If the class, `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` won't be found, `if (driver != null )` will never be executed because the control will either land into `catch` block or JVM will exit with `ClassNotFoundException`.